# How to get PHP shuffle results to show up one at a time throughout shuffle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Say I have 10 items in my db that I am trying to shuffle, how could I alter my current code so that every time it pulls a name out of the db that it shows up one at a time, rather than all at once?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "XXX");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

echo 'Normal results: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    echo 'Shuffled results: <br>';
    foreach ($array as $result) {
    $shuffle_firstname = $result['firstname'];
    $shuffle_lastname = $result['lastname'];
?>

<div id="shuffle_results">
        <?php echo $shuffle_firstname . ' ' . $shuffle_lastname . '<br>';?>
</div>
 <?php   }
}
```

//What I added in and this is the spot I added it as well

```
$get_shuffle = array($array);
$shuffle_one = array_pop($get_shuffle);
print_r($get_shuffle);
?>
```

I want them all to stay put once they have shown.. I just want all of them to come out one at a time. Say, there is 10 pieces of paper in a bag and you are drawing one at a time and then put the pieces of paper on a table to show what was drawn, that is what I want.

Comment: Put the results in an array and remove the item from the array when it is shown.

Comment: I want them all to stay put once they have shown.. I just want all of them to come out one at a time. Say, there is 10 pieces of paper in a bag and you are drawing one at a time and then put the pieces of paper on a table to show what was drawn, that is what I want. I will update my question.

Comment: Move the show items to a new array once they've been removed from the first array. Show the second array.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Put all of the items into an array (array_1). Then take one out of array_1, place it in array_2 and show it. Rinse, lather, repeat so that you're always showing array_2.

Comment: You lost me. I'm really new to php.

Comment: In your analogy the bag is array_1, the table array_2.

Comment: I'm not sure how to just take one item out at a time or remove one.

Comment: Sort the array like you would like then use either http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php to take the top item off or http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php to take the bottom item off of array_1

Comment: I updated my question and tried to do as one of thinks showed, but I am not getting anything other than a printed string - array().

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to do this with PHP. Get the results from your DB and send them to some JavaScript code. The JS can then handle the animation.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst what kind of JS code can handle what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to my comment suggesting you use JavaScript instead of PHP for the animation, here is a basic way to do it. (This code assumes you have jQuery on the page).

Note: I haven't tested this code and there is likely a bug or two, but I hope you get the general idea.

Your HTML

```
<div id="shuffle_results"></div>
<form onsubmit="getData()">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>
```

Your PHP

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array_push($array, $row);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Your JavaScript

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url to PHP script',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; ++i) {
        window.setTimeout(addResult, 2000, data[i].firstname, data[i].lastname);
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
      alert('Connection to script failed.\n\n' + textStatus + '\n\n' + error);
    }
  });
}

function addResult(firstname, lastname) {
  $('#shuffle_results').append("<p>" + firstname + " " + lastname + "</p>");
}
```

The basic idea here is that you shouldn't use PHP to do DOM manipulation. PHP can load data into your webpage (and that data can be DOM elements, JSON data as I have shown, or other types of data), but once there JavaScript should be used to interact with it. Recall, PHP runs on your server, while JavaScript (traditionally) runs in the client's web browser.

Comment: I get this error on this line... `echo json_encode(array);` for `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(array)' (array) (T_ARRAY_CAST), expecting ',' or ';' in`....Was the php in this supposed to replace all the php I had before?

Comment: Yes - the above code should replace all the code you have (not including other HTML you might have on your index.html). For the JavaScript, you can place it in its own file or between `<script></script>` tags on your index.html

Comment: Ok, I made my own file up for it to test. I'm still getting the error though for `echo json_encode(array);` . What could the error be?

Comment: Oh, haha. I forgot a `$` in the `json_encode(array)`. It should be  `json_encode($array)`. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. I have never had this happen before. Everything but the php is just showing up on the actual page(browser page) in html format? http://sundayfundayleague.com/test_shuffle.php

Comment: @Paul your webserver doesn't know how to render PHP. You should move the HTML and Javascript into a .html file, and the PHP into a .php file. Then make sure in the AJAX call to put the correct filename of the .php file. That should work.

Comment: I get a connection to script failed in the error box as well as it saying . Parse error and then below that, syntax error - Unexpected end of file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83483/discussion-between-matthew-herbst-and-paul).